# `arrange_venn()` fails to find a grid

Tags: r, complex-upset

`arrange_venn()` fails to find. This is the reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ComplexUpset)

venn_data <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~ind,  ~soz,  ~kri,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE,  TRUE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    FALSE,  TRUE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE,
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
    TRUE, FALSE,  TRUE
  )

arrange_venn(venn_data)
```

I tried to increase `max_iterations` to 50k, but that didn't help. What can I do to make the algorithm work?

Comment: Please provide the results you got, and describe the results you expected (and why)

Comment: Hmmm... might be a real bug.   `arrange_venn(venn_data[1:97,])`  runs fine, as does  `arrange_venn(venn_data[20:98])` , and `arrange_venn(venn_data[c(1:10,15:98),])`   but  `arrange_venn(venn_data[10:98,])`  fails as you describe.    Either there's something really strange about your first few rows vs. the last few, or this is a bug in `arrange_ven`

Comment: Then I tried   `arrange_venn(venn_data[1:98,], starting_grid_size = 50)` got this error:  "Error in rep(i, grid_size_y) : invalid 'times' argument"